# Como atualizar Gem no windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atualização, gem

Meu problema é que não consigo atualizar as `gem`

Baixei o `rubyInstaller` tentei rodar o comando para atualizar:

```
gem update rails --no-document
```

Mas infelizmente não atualiza dá o erro:

```
gem update rails --no-document
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Procurei online, mas nenhuma ajuda foi clara! Será que alguém conhece algum tutorial de como fazer funcionar?

Aprecio a ajuda!

Comment: Qual a sua versão do gem? (`gem --version`)

Answer (score 2):

Quando tive esse problema resolvi usando esse [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88), mas hoje em dia para Windows eu prefiro usar [JRuby](http://jruby.org/download), muito menos dores de cabeça.

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o seu problema seja resolvido ao reinstalar o rubygems:

1. Baixe o [RubyGems no formato zip](https://rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.6.8.zip)
2. Acesse o diretório onde você descompactou o rubygems
3. Execute `ruby setup.rb`
4. Teste executando a atualização `gem install --system`

Fiz também a instalação do [DevKit](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe).

1. Baixar, descompactar e acessar a pasta.
2. Executar os comandos `ruby dk.rb init` e `ruby dk.rb install` dentro da pasta em que foi descompactado o DevKit.